# What is the cause of a timeout error using input type="file" in classic asp site?

Tags: asp-classic, timeout

We have recently started experiencing timeout errors on an old (very old - 11 years!) portion of our website that we use internally, to maintain some content on another part of our site.

Basically the page involves browsing for a file and uploading it, with a link for users to view that file.

Whenever the file we select (using the input field) is large (say 10mg) and we submit the form, IE (or Chrome) times out. If we choose a small file (a few 100 kb) it works correctly.

I have narrowed the issue down to the use of the input type="file" element in this classic asp page.

I can reproduce the scenario with the most basic of HTML as follows;

```
<html>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" size="50" id="Test" name="Test" value="Test">
        <input type="submit" value="Test">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Selecting a small file here simply posts back and clears the form, while a large file appears to hang before reporting a timeout error.

I've tested this on IE9 and Chrome.

We have only just started experiencing this error - we don't even use the feature all that much but I would hazard a guess and say the last time anyone used it correctly was probably using IE8.

I am now going to attempt to test using older browsers.

**Does anyone know what could be causing this behaviour?**

So far I've searched IE 9 options for settings that may be affecting the timeout but none have jumped out at me. I've looked quickly at IIS settings too but nothing seemed obvious however I am far from an expert in this area (the server runs IIS 6 but we've reproduced this in a test environment running IIS 7 as well).

[Update]

Thanks to the suggestions so far, I have now tried;

- Resetting the file upload limit in the ASP config settings on IIS
- Adjusting the ASP timeout value on IIS Temporarily disabling
- Anti-Virus on the server and client.

(None of these have resolved the problem.)

Comment: What is the ASP Script Timeout value (I think it defaults to 90 seconds).   Most likely culprit.   It is buried somewhere under the default web site properties...

Comment: Yes - it was 90. I've pushed it right up (300) which hasn't worked but will keep tinkering. I'm sure it never took this long before though?

Comment: What about Anti Virus? From bad experience, some of those identify classic ASP interaction with the file system as malicious action and simply clock the ASP process, resulting in timeout. Disable any anti virus on the server (and also client computer) just for sake of debug and see if it help.

Comment: Thanks @Shadow Wizard, have tried this but it hasn't helped.

Comment: What about Sparky suggestions in his answer?

Comment: No - while a good clear answer with nice links, unfortunately they didn't help in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try adjusting the ASP time-out...

[IIS 6 ASP Default Timeout](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/2275a2ba-5b12-4e18-8266-8a3b0678e419.mspx?mfr=true)

I've had similar issues with large files in the past, many years ago with classic ASP,   I've also seen this issue when a file is larger than the IIS upload file size.  Hopefully, one of these two settings should let it work for you...

[File Upload Size Limit](http://www.banmanpro.com/support2/File_Upload_limits.asp)